# How to check the browser type and version then getting the proper css?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I want to be able to serve the proper css files depending on the user's browser type and version. In FF and Chrome, I have no problems at all. But when it comes to IE7-9, things start to look super weird and broken. I've written some IE specific css pages but unsure how to serve those css pages when the user uses IE.

Any js that can do this? Or even backend using java?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx. From that article, "Conditional comments are the preferred means of differentiating Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) rules intended for specific versions of Internet Explorer.".

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Comment: thanks all! ill make sure to look through those.

Comment: question, i just tried "    <!--[if IE 9]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ie.css"/>
    <![endif]-->
" but the     <!--[if IE 9]-->

    <![endif]--> will show up on the page, any way to hide that?

Comment: @yaojiang looks like you wrote it wrong; it is `<!--[if IE]>` .. `<![endif]-->` (note the `--` only appears in the close)

Comment: may this helps to http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write separate style sheet for Mozilla Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624208/how-to-write-separate-style-sheet-for-mozilla-firefox)

Answer (score 2):

Just use different CSS file for IE browser as below.

```
<!--[if IE 7.0]><link href="css/ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8.0]><link href="css/ie8.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9.0]><link href="css/ie8.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" /><![endif]-->
```

Comment: It's important to note that conditional IE tags as outlined above no longer work in IE10 and above.

Answer (score 1):

There are bunch of ways to do this. But most likely you will only need to address Internet Explorer, and pretty much rest of the browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc handle the websites quite similarly.

You can simple HTML conditionals like

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

In which change your desired IE version.

However, if you still need and wish to address more than one browser, you should do some simple php, use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) with [this](http://www.user-agents.org/), it's not the best way to deal things like this since user agent can always be changed and shouldn't be relied on. You can do a similar thing in JS too, but php is more desirable for redirects and loading content with conditionals.